# How to get recent unique user list from message table with user personal data from different tables

Tags: mysql

I have 5 tables name as the **message, users, teachers, students, and schools** (Please note that schools mean school admin here)
I'm creating a simple messaging application where

**schools (i.e admin)** can message to teachers and students

**teachers** can message to school admin and students

**students** can message to teachers only

I want to fetch recent messages with unique users details like name, profile picture from messaging table for a particular user.

For Example: Suppose I'm school admin and I have sent so many messages to teacher_A, teacher_B, student_A, student_B. I need a query that can fetch recent messages of my with unique users. Like here it query should return all 4 users_id, name, profile, and last message from **schools, teachers, and students** table accordingly with correct data.

I have created a Routine in mysql with the parameters user_id and sch_id (i.e school_id)

```
(SELECT "admin" as type, message.to_user_id, message.from_user_id, message, schools.name,schools.logo as profile FROM `message`
JOIN schools ON message.to_user_id = schools.user_id
WHERE
(message.from_user_id = userid OR message.to_user_id = userid) AND message.school_id = sch_id
GROUP BY message.to_user_id ORDER BY send_date DESC)
UNION
(SELECT "teacher" as type, message.to_user_id, message.from_user_id, message, CONCAT(teachers.firstname,CONCAT(" ",teachers.lastname)) as name, teachers.profile_picture as profile FROM `message`
JOIN teachers ON message.to_user_id = teachers.user_id
WHERE
(message.from_user_id = userid OR message.to_user_id = userid) AND message.school_id = sch_id
 GROUP BY message.to_user_id ORDER BY send_date DESC
)
UNION 
(SELECT "student" as type, message.to_user_id, message.from_user_id, message, CONCAT(students.firstname,CONCAT(" ",students.lastname)) as name, students.picture as profile FROM `message`
JOIN students ON message.to_user_id = students.user_id
WHERE
(message.from_user_id = userid OR message.to_user_id = userid) AND message.school_id = sch_id
GROUP BY message.to_user_id ORDER BY send_date DESC)
```

**Message Table**

[image]

When I run the above query it'll show result like this:

[image]

In the above image, I'm getting wrong data with the name of admin. I'm logged in as Admin, it is showing logged in user name instead of another user name.
The above query is showing correct data when I logged in as a school admin. But when I logged in as teacher I got the same message with the same teacher name that is logged in not by the name of school admin.

Comment: Can add sample output & expected output.

Comment: @RahulSingh Okay